# Cannot perform segue to another ViewController after showing the present one with a clear background

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, segue, presentviewcontroller

I followed Ray Wenderlich [tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/94565/how-to-create-an-ios-book-open-animation-part-1) on how to create an iOS book animation, now i'm trying to perform some changes to it.

**Original project** is composed of `Navigation Controller`, `Books View Controller` - showing an array of books, by clicking on a book you can open it - and `Book View Controller` - showing the selected book open.

**What i've added:** a `View Controller` and set it as initial VC; a `UIButton`which perform a show segue to `Navigation Controller`.

[image: Here is my storyboard]

I want to show `View Controller` in background after `Books View Controller` appears but apparently iOS removes the view controllers underneath it from the view hierarchy, this leading to a black background if i set `clearColor` in the Attributes inspector. I've then added the following code to `ViewController.swift` to have a transparent background.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    let vc = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("BooksViewController") as! BooksViewController
    vc.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    vc.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.OverCurrentContext
    self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

It works well and i can see the initial VC in the background while seeing the array of books, but i can no longer perform segue to `Book View Controller` by clicking on a book. So apparently `openBook` in `BooksViewController` is never called:

```
func selectedCell() -> BookCoverCell? {
    if let indexPath = collectionView?.indexPathForItemAtPoint(CGPointMake(collectionView!.contentOffset.x + collectionView!.bounds.width / 2, collectionView!.bounds.height / 2)) {
        if let cell = collectionView?.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as? BookCoverCell {
            return cell
        }
    }
    return nil
}

func openBook(book: Book?) {
    let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("BookViewController") as! BookViewController
    vc.book = selectedCell()?.book
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
        return
    })
}
```

I cannot understand where the problem is, any help is really appreciated. Please be gentle, i'm still learning Swift and english is not my native language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using prepareForSegue incorrectly. You do not want to present a view controller in your prepareForSegue. Use segue.destinationViewController as! YourViewController to reference it instead